# Arduino 101 and BLE

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using Arduino 101 and a HM-10 Module(BLE). I want to make an android app to send and receive data from Arduino via this Bluetooth module.
I was unable send data or receive data. I was able to connect to module.
Can you tell me a good tutorial how to do it? or to provide some useful information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to figure with the same problem currently on IOS, but i have found a good example Project to get startet. Look for one on the internet. Best is to look for a example that is basically a Serial Monitor/Terminal. After you have found your Example you should be able to modify it after your needs.